# How to add npm modules in telerik nativescript app

Tags: ios, npm, telerik, nativescript, telerik-appbuilder

I'd like to use the telerik platform as my primary development platform for mobile dev but I'm facing an issue when trying out a sample app on physical hardware.

Using telerik platform with a nativescript angular2 app .
I succeed into running the app on the telerik app on iPhone, even if the 'setting up livesync' takes forever and does not work in the end, maybe there's something I dont't get about it, but anyway, I use the 3 fingers shortcut to reload changes.

When I try to load npm modules : I get how to import them in telerik platform. I do it in the code section, then inside the properties, in the 'Dependencies' tab, there I choose Install from Plugins Marketplace,  choosing NPM, I install whatever module.

I tried to install moment, this worked just fine, then I tried to install other npm modules ( nativescript-socketio and nativescript-socket.io) but the launch on the iPhone always fails with the red screen of death and a message telling it is unable to find the required files.

I found out that there is a plugin list on the Telerik iPhone app (under Help & About -> NativeScript ->Plugins ) where moment is listed and not the other plugins...
So how do I try my app with other plugins? is there a way to import the node_modules?

Answer (score 2):

Node/npm modules should work as long as they not depend on npm if its some javascript code for example email validation u can install with `npm install <name of plugin>` and after adding plugin u need to use `tns run android/ios` as livesync not update node_modules folder for use inside of app